# JS Date output into Hidden Text Field

Tags: java, php, javascript, mysql

I am using datejs (see www.datejs.com) to work out date and time for tomorrow (24 hours into the future) and output the date into hidden text box to be inserted into db.

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// submitted
var d1 = Date.today().add(1).days();
document.write(d1.toString('d MMMM yyyy')); //Need to change this to MYSQL format
</script>

<input name="referral_to_be_accepted_by" type="text" value="" id="referral_to_be_accepted_by"/>
```

At the moment the date (need to add time as well) is shown in doc, but need to put it in the text box?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `document.getElementById("referral_to_be_accepted_by").value = d1.toString('d MMMM yyyy');`

Edit:

```
<input name="referral_to_be_accepted_by" type="text" value="" id="referral_to_be_accepted_by"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
// submitted
var d1 = Date.today().add(1).days();
document.getElementById("referral_to_be_accepted_by").value = d1.toString('d MMMM yyyy'); //Need to change this to MYSQL format
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to put in name of form?

Comment: put your `input` tag above your `script`.  The way it is now it's trying to assign a value to an input that doesn't yet exist (see my edit);

Comment: That did it! Thank you Marek.. Is the comment by nategood an issue for me??

Comment: not really as far as I can tell - DateJS itself allows you to pass a format to `toString` so you should be good (I've used it in projects without problems)